# Determinig the number of hidden states in a Hidden Markov Model

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, hidden-markov-models, feature-extraction

I am learning about Hidden Markov Models for classifying motion in a sequence of t image frames.

Assume I have m dimensions of feature from each frame. Then I cluster it into a symbol (for observable symbol). And I create k different HMM model for k class.

Then, how do I determine the number of hidden states for each model to optimise prediction ?

Btw, is my approach correct? If I misunderstood how to use it, please correct me:)

Thanks :)

Comment: Hard to answer because we don't know how your are planning to use your 'm' HMMs models for a unique prediction. Something is missing here. Strange to use multiple model for one problem strongly coupled.

Comment: if I want to use HMM for classification a sequence, is that right if I create multiple HMM model for each class and I try to get the highest probability from all of that model to become the winner ?

Comment: sorry I made mistake, I already update my question

Comment: Number of hidden states in something which is not very straightforward to conclude. To do this domain knowledge comes into picture but of course can be figured out by trail and error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### "is my approach already correct?"

Your current approach is correct. I have done the same thing some weeks ago and had asked the same questions. I have built a gesture recognition tool.

You say you have k classes you want to recognize, so yes, you will train k HMM. For each HMM you run Forward algorithm and receive `P(HMM|observation)` for each hidden markov model (alternatively Viterbi decoding is also possible). Then you take the one with the highest probability.

It's also correct to see the m-dimensional feature vector as a single observation symbol. Depending on what your vector looks like, you might want to use a continuous hidden markov model or a discrete hidden markov model. Working with discrete ones is often easier and easier to train with little training data. So in case your feature vector space is continuous, you might want to consider discretization to make all values discrete (e.g. through uniform classes).
The question about discreteness is: How many classes of observations will you have?

### "how to determine the number of hidden state for each model to get optimal prediction?"

However, I cannot fully answer your actual question about the number of hidden states. From what I have been taught in other areas, it seems like it's a lot of benchmarking and testing. E.g. in speech recongition we use 3 HMM states for each phonem (human sound), because sounds sound different at the beginning, in the middle and at the end. And then each different phonem gets one triple. But that was of course engineering.

In my own application I have thought like this: I wanted to define gestures and associate them with directions. Like `open_firefox = [UP, RIGHT]`. So I decided to use four hidden states for all four directions.
I guess finding out the best number of states is a lot about engineering and trying out different things.

Comment: thx for your explaination, 

I want to ask another question, you used 4 hidden states because you have four direction. Isn't the direction is the observable variable ? Not the hidden one ? CMIIW

Comment: Actually yes. In my case it's both, so I have not been sure if HMM is actually the really required way to model this. However, I have learned HMM a lot and solved it like this: For definition of states, I only used 4 directions UP, RIGHT, LEFT, DOWN, because that's what I will use in the definition of gestures. However, for observations I use 8 directions (actually movement would be continuous, but I am mapping it onto the 8 directions with `atan2`). It would probably be possible to make it more advanced by abstracting states more from movement, but that was my first and an easy idea.

Comment: would you mind to illustrate your hidden markov model (the relation between your hidden states & observable) ? , maybe I can use your model to implement my task. Thanks :)

Comment: I wrote a [German article about my tool](http://eliteinformatiker.de/2013/06/22/einen-gestenerkenner-mit-hidden-markov-models-programmieren/). You could scroll down to the bottom. The last piece of sourcecode is responsible for generating the probmatrices for the HMM. It generally goes like this: State-UP has higher prob for Emission-UP and Emission-UPRIGHT than for Emission-DOWN etc. And State-transition probs depend on the gesture for each HMM (e.g. gesture DOWN-RIGHT has high prob for State-DOWN to State-RIGHT and high for State-DOWN to State-DOWN, but low for State-DOWN to State-LEFT).