# sequence prediction using HMM Matlab

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, sequence, prediction, hidden-markov-models

I'm currently learning the `murphyk's` toolbox for Hidden Markov's Model, However I'v a problem of determining my model's coefficients and also the algorithm for the sequence prediction by log likelihood.

**My Scenario:**

I have the flying bird's trajectory in 3D-space i.e its `X`,`Y` and `Z` which lies in *Continuous* HMM's category. I'v the 200 observations of flying bird i.e 500 rows data of trajectory, and I want to predict the sequence. I want to sample that in 20 datapoints . i.e after 10 points, so my first question is, Is following parameters are valid for my case?

```
  O = 3;  %Number of coefficients in a vector 
  T = 20; %Number of vectors in a sequence 
  nex = 50; %Number of sequences 
  M = 2;  %Number of mixtures 
  Q = 20; %Number of states
```

And the second question is, What algorithm is appropriate for sequence prediction and is training is compulsory for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, I'm assuming you're training 200 different classes (HMMs) and each class has 500 training examples (observation sequences).

`O` is the dimensionality of vectors, seems to be correct.

There is no need to have a fixed `T`, it depends on the observation sequences you have.

`M` is the number of multivariate Gaussians (or mixtures) in the GMM of a state. More will fit to your data better and give you better accuracy, but at the cost of performance. Choose a suitable value.

`N` does not need to be equal to `T`. For the best number of states `N`, you'll have to benchmark and see yourself:

[Determinig the number of hidden states in a Hidden Markov Model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17565600/determinig-the-number-of-hidden-states-in-a-hidden-markov-model)

Yes, you have to train your classes using the Baum-Welch algorithm, optionally preceded by something like the segmental k-means procedure. After that you can easily perform isolated unit recognition using Forward/Backward probability or Viterbi probability by simply selecting the class with the highest probability.

Comment: Awesome explanation, hats off.. :-)

Comment: i'd like U to answer my unsatisfied questions, U have grate ability of understanding and let other know well, also please tell, which `tag` u ur using mostly?

Comment: @AhsanAli I see most of your questions deal with Matlab, sorry but I don't have any knowledge of that.

Comment: OK, anyways your knowledge and concepts are mind blowing, tell me a thing, I created HMM training model by EM, I'm thinking that if miss-classification occurs, it should apply viterbi, is it logically possible?

Comment: Apply Viterbi to what?

Comment: Viterbi if it is missclasified/outlier ? @Max